# Do I need a double save() after a domain modification using afterInsert()?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class that modifies one of its properties in the `afterInsert` event.

A small example:

```
class Transaction {
   Long transactionId

   static constraints = {
       transactionId nullable: true
   }

   def afterInsert() {
       // copy the record id to transactionId;
       transactionId = id
   }
}
```

**Whenever I save the domain object** (`transaction.save(flush: true)`) **in
my unit tests, all is well,** and the `transactionId` is updated. But **when I try to find the saved record** using `Transaction.findByTransactionId()`, **I get no results:**

```
   // do something
   transaction.save(flush: true)
   Transaction transaction = Transaction.findByTransactionId(1)
   // !! no results; transaction == null
```

And I have to do a double `save()` before I can find the record using `findByTransactionId()`:

```
   // do something
   transaction.save(flush: true)
   transaction.save(flush: true)
   Transaction transaction = Transaction.findByTransactionId(1)
   // !! it works....
```

The double `save()` seems awkward. Any suggestions on how to eliminate the need for it?

Comment: You should check the save for errors. if (!transaction.save()) { } See http://blog.springsource.org/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/ for more info on this.

Comment: The save does not give me errors, i omitted that code.

Comment: Can you try something for me?  Can you put `assert null != id` inside of your afterInsert?

Comment: I added the suggested code 'assert null != id' and it makes no difference. The id is nicely filled so the assertion is ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This small piece of code makes it obviously work:

```
def afterInsert() {
    transactionId = id
    save() // we need to call save to persist the changens made to the object
}
```

So calling save in the afterInsert is needed to persist the changes made in afterInsert!

Comment: I would avoid using this code to solve the problem in a high volume case.  You'll be locking the table twice for insert and returning the persisted entity twice because your using `save()`.  Instead you should do this in your unit test and not in the code base.

Comment: Not using the save in the afterInsert() may result in logical errors as a developer should be aware that in the codebase a save should be called twice. So the solution to put the logic in one place seems reasonable. The unit test clearly made me aware of this problem. Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The call to [`save()`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) will return the persisted entity if validation passes, so there isn’t any reason to look it up separately afterwards. I think that your problem is that you’re re-instantiating the `transaction` variable (using that same name).  If you must look it up (I don’t suggest doing so), call it something else.  Also, the `1` id that you’re looking up may not exist if the column is an `AUTO-INCREMENT`.

```
      def a = a.save(flush: true)
      a?.refresh() // for afterInsert()
      Transaction b = (a == null) ? null : Transaction.findByTransactionId(a.id)
      // (Why look it up? You already have it.)
```

**Update:**

Because you’re using  `afterInsert()`, Hibernate may not realize that it needs to refresh the object. Try using [the `refresh()` method](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/refresh.html) after you call `save()`.

Comment: The code is for test purpose, in my actualcode i persist the Transaction which works perfect. Then later on i some other piece of code i want to find the Transaction based on the value is set in the afterInsert. Then whatever i do, the record can not be found. The value that is set in the afterInsert is not persisted. So that is why i need a double save. I followed your suggestion and made another variable with a total different name. This had no effect.

Comment: I did put breakpoints in my service and executed the following steps.. 1) Transaction.list() which returned a list of transactions with the variables. I inspected the transactions and tried a findBy<field with has been set in the afterinsert> result == null. The same findBy on fields which are not set in the afterInsert and voila.. they are found.. So whatever field i set in the afterInsert, i am not able to use the findBy on that field. Inspecting the objects on runtime showed me that the fields are correctly filled. So i am lost on where to search..

Comment: After thinking about it I've updated my answer.  Try the refresh method after save.

Comment: I modified the code and this also makes no difference. When changing a property in the afterInsert the use of refresh results in losing those changes.

Comment: This small piece of code makes it obviously work:

    def afterInsert() {
        transactionId = id
        save()
    }

So calling save in the afterInsert is needed to persist the changes made in afterInsert